# Error 32600: JSON-RPC Request must be an object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rpc, json-rpc

My request is:

```
var req = {"action": "UserAPI","method": "Authenticate","data": ["un","pw"],"type": "rpc", "tid": "1"}
$.post("http://localhost/myServer/RPC/ROUTER",req, function(result){
        console.log(result.responseText);
    });
```

Response is:

```
"{ "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : { "code" : -32600, "message" : "JSON-RPC Request must be an object." }, "tid" : null }"
```

Request is already an object. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is expecting a JSON-RPC request, then you need to format your request the way it wants.

JSON-RPC means that the server wants a JSON string as the POST body, not form data like you are sending.

Try this:

```
var req = {
    "action": "UserAPI",
    "method": "Authenticate",
    "data": ["un","pw"],
    "type": "rpc", 
    "tid": "1"
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/myServer/RPC/ROUTER",
    type: 'post',
    // This tells the server we are sending
    // JSON data as the payload
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // Encode the object as a JSON string
    data: JSON.stringify(req),
    // The response is JSON
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        // This should be parsed for you, so `result` will be an object
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```